# What's cheaper: Traversal using n iterators of a single ConcurrentHashMap or n instances of a HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Imagine a producer-consumer scenario, thread A produces entries, one to many other threads consume them.

For this I am passing a bunch of entries to each consumer thread.

Do do this I am asking myself if it's cheaper (primary in sense of cpu utlization, secondary in memory):

- to provide each consumer thread a seperate instance of a `HashMap`. After passing the `Map` to one consumer, a new instance of the `Map` will created and used for passing the next produced entries to the next thread

or

- to use a single `ConcurrentHashMap` and create an `Iterator` for each consumer threads and after passing the `Iterator` to the thread clearing the `Map` - so that each Iterator contains its own view of the underlying `Map`.

What do you think? Is a more-or-less generic answer possible?
Or is it strongly dependent of some variables like number of entries, threads etc?
**EDIT:** Or should I use some other kind of data structure which may better solve these kinds of problems?

Comment: +1 interesting question.  `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` almost does this, but not quite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The java concurrent package provides a data structure for exact this scenario.

@see `java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque`

But please do some perfomance test: because the results stongly depends on you use case. And **if this is only micro optimization, than a: clean, easy to understand, thread save approach would be much better than performance optimization whithout impact.**

Comment: I'd give you another vote for the update if I could. I've yet to see a Java application where this level of optimisation would make a tangible difference.

Comment: Would a java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue also do the job? If not, why?

Comment: @MRalwasser: ArrayBlockingQueue is designed for this type of tasks

Answer (score 0):

The most expensive thing cpu-wise is threads contention. Seems, your first approach will produce no contention at all -- each thread will have it's local version of Map -- at the expense of higher memory consumption.
I'd, for one, benchmark two scenarios for several setups (nr of threads, sizes of map, etc) that make sense. It's hard to tell exact figures without benchmark.